# encfs 1.7 1.8 nameio version 4:0:0 incompatibility

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, encfs

I created an encfs encrypted directory on Ubuntu 16.04 encfs version 1.8.1, and synchronised the encrypted directory with a second machine running 14.04 encfs version 1.7.4.

I am unable to decrypt the directory on the second machine.  The error given is:
*(FileUtils.cpp:1649) Unable to find nameio interface nameio/block, version 4:0:0*
(full log below).

I presume that I need to upgrade encfs from version 1.7.4 to version 1.8 (or similar) on the second machine.  Can anyone advise me on how to do that (without upgrading to 16.04)?  To my surprise, it seems hard to find information on how to do this.

Thank you.

09:29:27 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
09:29:27 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:370) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16
09:29:30 (FileUtils.cpp:1628) cipher key size = 52
09:29:30 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if nameio/block(3:0:1) implements nameio/block(4:0:0)
09:29:30 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if nameio/null(1:0:0) implements nameio/block(4:0:0)
09:29:30 (Interface.cpp:165) checking if nameio/stream(2:1:2) implements nameio/block(4:0:0)
09:29:30 (FileUtils.cpp:1649) Unable to find nameio interface nameio/block, version 4:0:0

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use 1.8.1 created data with the 1.7.4 program. Often times data from newer versions of programs just isn't compatible with older versions of programs, so it just won't work. Backwards compatibility is often do-able, but forwards compatibility is another beast.

Your best bet may be to try a secure file transfer (ssh?) or send a more universally compatible file format, maybe a .tar.gz.gpg archive (pipe into gpg to avoid unencrypted files lying around) or a LUKS container.

In general you can't upgrade everything on an old version of Ubuntu to the same versions as a new Ubuntu. There may be a backport available, but I don't see one for Encfs, or a PPA, or you could try searching https://packages.ubuntu.com and just try directly installing the newer packages (from 16.04) on your old (14.04) system but it's not guaranteed, or even likely to succeed, and could even create conflicts and "break" important things too.